# How can i debug my application in my windows phone 8?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, windows-phone-7, visual-studio-2012, windows-phone-8

Am using Visual Studio 2010 and developed a application and debugged it in a windows phone 7.5, after registering with [windows phone developer Registration] app.

Now i got a new windows phone 8, i could not register because i read that, the windows phone 8 will not be supported by zune. Without zune [windows phone developer Registration] will not detect your phone.

Some people says i need to use Visual studio 2012 for windows phone 8, then the problem i have i am using only windows 7 desktop operating system. Visual studio 2012 needs windows 8 desktop operating system.

Please suggest me can i run my app in windows phone 8 with visual studio 2010.

If the only way is to develop in Visual studio 2012 then will my application support for windows phone 7.

Please help me with your suggestions and answers.

Answer (score 1):

That is how it is, you need VS2012 for WP8, which itself needs Windows 8. You can always download an evaluation version of both and use them, eventually inside a virtual machine. Pretty much the same story than for developing Windows 8 applications.

Regarding compatibility between phone versions, Microsoft recompiles WP7 apps so they can run on WP8 but I'm unaware this happening the other way around.

WP8 doesn't need Zune and it's not available anyway on Windows 8.

I myself had to switch to Windows 8 for this very reason...

Comment: Thank you buddy. Hope i need to switch to windows 8 SDK and windows 8 operating system. and also i got this link http://dev.windowsphone.com/en-us/downloadsdk
so hope developing with windows 8 sdk supports for windows phone 7.5 also